# Configuring CORS for nginx and passenger

Tags: nginx, cors, passenger

I'm have an Rails application with Angular. I'm using nginx and passenger as a server. The idea is that angular makes requests to the api.app.com. When I try to do this I get this error.

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.app.com/api/some_resource. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://www.app.com' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.`

My current nginx configuration handles CORS requests this way:

```
server {
    location / {
        set $cors '';

        if ($http_origin ~* 'https?://(localhost|www\.app-staging\.com|www\.app\.com|api.app.com|app.com)') {
            set $cors 'true';
        }

        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;

        if ($cors = 'true') {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "$http_origin";
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS';
            #add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Accept,Authorization,Cache-Control,Content-Type,DNT,If-Modified-Since,Keep-Alive,Origin,User-Agent,X-Mx-ReqTok$
        }
    }
}
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are wrapping the match with `'`, which is not required. Also, remember that the `.` is a special value in a regular expression.

```
if ($http_origin ~* (localhost|www\.app-staging\.com|www\.app\.com|api\.app\.com|app\.com)) {
  set $cors 'true';
}
```

Remember to restart the server or reload the configuration after the change.

Comment: Besides, remember to put a $ at the end of matching domain or you could be open to attacks. Check https://gist.github.com/Stanback/7145487#gistcomment-2044821 for more information.